# 'self' used in property access 'questionNumber' before all stored properties are initialized (Combine)

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm developing a quiz app for tvOS with *Swift* and *SwiftUI* framework. I have a **QuestionBank** class and **Question** struct to set my questions and I made a **QuizManager** class that interacts with the game View coded with SwiftUI. So I'll pass data using *Combine* framework.

But it's getting tricky when in QuizManager, I want to declare **@Published** variables whereas some of these variables need another #Published variable to be computed. Indeed I have 3 @Published variables at the moment:

- questionNumber
- questionText
- answers

This is my code for QuizManager :

```
import Combine
import Foundation

class QuizManager: ObservableObject {
    var questionBank: QuestionBank

    @Published var questionNumber = 0
    @Published var questionText: String
    @Published var answers: [String]

    func updateQuestion() {
        self.questionNumber += 1
    }

    init() {
        self.questionNumber = 0
        self.questionBank = QuestionBank()
        self.questionText = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].questionText
        self.answers = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].answers
    }

}
```

As you can see I must init questionNumber before using it to init the other @Published variables.

Answer (score 1):

As I found out myself, I didn't need to set **questionNumber** as a **@Published** variable, but I needed to reset **questionText** and **answers** values in the **update()** function so that the UI updates itself when **@Published** variables changed.

Here's the final code :

```
class QuizManager: ObservableObject {
    var questionBank: QuestionBank
    var questionNumber: Int

    @Published var questionText: String
    @Published var answers: [String]

    func updateQuestion() {
        self.questionNumber += 1
        self.questionText = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].questionText
        self.answers = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].answers
    }

    init() {
        self.questionNumber = 0
        self.questionBank = QuestionBank()
        self.questionText = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].questionText
        self.answers = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].answers
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix

```
init() {
    let questionNumber = 0 // use local tmp var
    self.questionNumber = questionNumber
    self.questionBank = QuestionBank()
    self.questionText = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].questionText
    self.answers = questionBank.questions[questionNumber].answers
}
```

Comment: I just found a solution myself, but your code may work. Thanks for the help 